# Blazor Server .NET 5 Identity Authentication from razor page

Tags: razor, asp.net-identity, blazor, .net-5

I am just looking into .Net Core's Identity system for authentication I have a home screen (a razor page with `@page "/"`) that has a login form. I would like to use this login form to authenticate the user.

Every example I've seen seems to use `Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Login.cshtml` generated from the Identity.UI package, I would like to avoid this and ideally I would like to be able to authenticate a user from a Razor component thus allowing me to authenticate from any page.

However, from what I've read for reasons I don't yet understand fully that's not possible. I'm not sure if this information is out of date.

So, is it possible to authenticate a user using `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` from a razor page or component in .NET 5?

Comment: Note the antiforgery token....

Comment: It is possible but it is not recommended, By default you authenticate users in MVC or Razor Pages and redirect them to the Blazor pages.

Comment: Yep.  The day I can dump MVC scaffolded Identity pages for pure Blazor is going to be a happy day for me.  *holds breath*

Comment: Thanks Ali, Benny, I thought as much!

Comment: Why do you refuse to accept any solution that is offered to you, like, you just downvote, for real? any way.. gf&hf

Comment: I don't  feel either of the answers you gave, as answers, were actually very good. Your first attempt was completely irrelevant and your second attempt had no meaningful information.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Hello from 2022, I hope you have some breath left...